# Trouble when linking Objective-C program with my own libobjc.A.dylib

Tags: objective-c, linker, runtime, clang

I builded a custom libobjc.A.dylib from the source of apple's open source website and I want to debug it by compiling a simple program with the dylib, but it seems the clang always using the system libobjc.A.dylib.

The compile command is:

```
xcrun --sdk macosx10.8 clang main.m -std=c99 -framework Foundation -lobjc -I./usr/include -L.
```

the libobjc.A.dylib is in the current folder. And the otool command tells me which library the program links with:

```
~ otool -L a.out
a.out:
    /System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Versions/C/Foundation (compatibility version 300.0.0, current version 945.18.0)
    /usr/lib/libobjc.A.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 228.0.0)
    /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 169.3.0)
    /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/Versions/A/CoreFoundation (compatibility version 150.0.0, current version 744.19.0)
```

In the http://opensource.apple.com/source/objc4/objc4-551.1/test/test.pl file, it's using a flag called -fno-objc-link-runtime, but it seems it's not working with my laptop(mac 10.9.4, xcode 5.1.1)

Tried setting DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH environment var, but it's not working. Here is the folder which I compiled the code https://github.com/Jeswang/Compile-Issue, any suggestion or solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, I used **install_name_tool** command to change the library's link:

```
install_name_tool -change /usr/lib/libobjc.A.dylib @executable_path/libobjc.A.dylib main
```

Useful links:

[dyld manual](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/dyld.1.html)

[mikeash.com: Friday Q&A 2009-11-06: Linking and Install Names](https://www.mikeash.com/pyblog/friday-qa-2009-11-06-linking-and-install-names.html)